# ObjectDumper class in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning `LINQ`. Several examples use `ObjectDumper`. What is the use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a helper class defined in the sample that prints out the contents of the sequence and properties of an object to the console so that you can investigate it. It uses reflection to do so.